# Combine path from two parameters in XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, path

I have a simple question. How do you combine a path from two template parameters? I would like to do something like that:

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='show:show']">
<xsl:param name="arg1"/>
<xsl:param name="arg2"/>
<tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1,$arg2)"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

to get path like: arg1/arg2 but it doesn't work. How can I do that properly?
or can you do sth like

```
<xsl:value-of select="path/path/$arg2"/>
```

?
**arg1** is complete path from root and **arg2** is single element name.

Comment: Are your arg1 and arg2 complete path expressions you want to combine or are they just single element names?

Comment: arg1 is complete path from root and arg2 is single element name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build path expressions as strings and then evaluate them you need an extension function (at least in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0), there's nothing in the core spec to support it but most processors provide a suitable function. The expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1,'/',$arg2)"/>
```

would result in a string containing the string value of `arg1`, a slash, and the string value of `arg2`. But if arg1 is a node set and you restrict arg2 to be just an element name then you can do something like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$arg1/*[local-name() = $arg2]"/>
```

(or `copy-of` as appropriate) and call the template like

```
<xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="/path/to/interesting/stuff" />
<xsl:with-param name="arg2" select="'elementname'" />
```

If you wanted to allow for arg2 to name an attribute rather than an element use

```
$arg1/@*[.....]
```

Or to allow it to be either (assuming the target of `arg1` doesn't have an attribute *and* a child element with the same name)

```
$arg1/node()[......]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1,'/',$arg2)"/>
```

Comment: thanks but i only get "arg1 /" then. I mean contents of elements in path, saved in arg1 ended with a "/"

Comment: couldn't get you probably arg2 is empty. do <message>

Comment: I just wrapped my <xsl:value-of.. line with <xsl:message> ant it returned: data1 data2 data3 ... /